# Why doesn't my WP Meta Query return any results?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, query, meta-query

Is it not OK to accept a value from $_GET as the key in a WP Meta Query? I'm not sure why this code doesn't return any results...

BOTH the queries for Price as well as bedrooms do not return any results. Is my code incorrect? Any help will be much appreciated..

```
<?php
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
$paged = get_query_var('paged');
} else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
$paged = get_query_var('page');
} else {
$paged = 1;
}
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'property',
'paged' => $paged
);

if($_GET['beds'] >= 1) {
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
'key' => $_GET['beds'],
'value' => array('pyre_BHK-A','pyre_BHK-B','pyre_BHK-C','pyre_BHK-D','pyre_BHK-E'),
'compare' => 'IN'
);
}

if(($_GET['price-max'] >= 1)&&($_GET['price-min'] >= 1)) {
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
'relation' => 'OR',
array(
'key' => 'pyre_price',
'value' => array($_GET['price-min'],$_GET['price-max']),
'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
'type' => 'numeric'
),
array(
'key' => 'pyre_pricem',
'value' => array($_GET['price-min'],$_GET['price-max']),
'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
'type' => 'numeric'
)
);
}

query_posts($args);
if(have_posts()):
?>

<?php
while(have_posts()): the_post();
?>


<?php get_template_part( 'property-listing' );           // Navigation bar (property-listing.php) ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>
<h3><?php echo of_get_option('search_results_none_title', 'No properties were found which match your search criteria.'); ?></h3>
<p><?php echo of_get_option('search_results_none_content', 'Try broadening your search to find more results.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what are the keys which you are getting using `$_GET` and why you are comparing it using `>= int`

Comment: @Anjum I'm getting the number of bedrooms ($_GET['beds']) and maximum price ($_GET['price-max']) and minimum price ($_GET['price-min']) from the user. 

I never used >= where did you see that? I'm only comparing using 'IN' and 'BETWEEN'

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors on how `meta_query` array is setted for `price-max` and `price-min`.

Also in your code will be an issue if no `$_GET['beds']` are sended but `$_GET['price-min']` and `$_GET['price-max']` are. this because the `$args['meta_query']` array is setted inside `if($_GET['beds'] >= 1)`.

Moreover your code will throw a lot of notices if the `GET` are not sended, you have to check if `$_GET` variables are set before using and, in addition, you should ensure them are numeric values if you want to use as numeric.

Finally, `query_posts` should always be avoided, use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead.

This code should work, but is **untested**:

```
<?php
if ( ! is_front_page() ) {
  $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? : 1;
} else {
  $paged = get_query_var('page') ? : 1;
}

$beds = isset($_GET['beds']) && intval($_GET['beds']) ? $_GET['beds'] : 0;
$max = isset($_GET['price-max']) && intval($_GET['price-max']) ? $_GET['price-max'] : 0;
$min = isset($_GET['price-min']) && intval($_GET['price-min']) ? $_GET['price-min'] : 0;

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'property',
  'paged' => $paged
);

if( $beds >= 1) {
  $args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => $beds, // are you sure for that?
    'value' => array('pyre_BHK-A','pyre_BHK-B','pyre_BHK-C','pyre_BHK-D','pyre_BHK-E'),
    'compare' => 'IN'
  );
}

if( ($max >= 1) && ($min) ) {
  if ( ! isset($args['meta_query']) ) $args['meta_query'] = array();
  $args['meta_query']['relation'] = 'OR';
  $args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => 'pyre_price',
    'value' => array($min, $max),
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    'type' => 'numeric'
  );
  $args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => 'pyre_pricem',
    'value' => array($min, $max),
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    'type' => 'numeric'
  );
}

$query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();

get_template_part( 'property-listing' );
// Navigation bar (property-listing.php)

endwhile;

else:
?>  
<h3><?php echo of_get_option('search_results_none_title', 'No properties were found which match your search criteria.'); ?></h3>
<p><?php echo of_get_option('search_results_none_content', 'Try broadening your search to find more results.'); ?></p>
<?php
wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
?>
```

Comment: +1 from me, it's exactly what i want to say, but i was gone to meet a friend and now i am ...